# Can 2 Vf pages use the same controller and share the data

Tags: apex, visualforce

Here is a scenario where i have a search page with filters for users to select and display the search results. I also have a button to generate the pdf.

I have a list of account in the controller which displays the search result. I am doing the exact same thing in the page i am generating the pdf except that i am passing the selected parameters into vf page rendered as pdf and requerying it  and generating the list.

These work fine.. But now i need to give an ability to remove some search result records and this needs to be generated as pdf.

I was wondering if i can share the data from the search page to VF page if i was using the same controller?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the view state will be shared across Pages, which share a controller, so long as you don't perform a redirect, because this [flushes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm) the view state.

> If **set to true**, a redirect is performed through a client side
>   redirect. This type of redirect performs an HTTP GET request, and
>   **flushes the view state**, which uses POST. If set to **false**, the redirect
>   is a server-side forward that **preserves the view state** if and only if
>   the target page uses the same controller and contains the proper
>   subset of extensions used by the source page.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can! I have the same application where the user can search for some data and then export it as pdf file. So i have created two pages with only one controller. The search page use the `ApexPages.StandardSetController` because of pagination for the search results.

Here is a smal example of the controller:

```
public with sharing MyController(){

    // The standard set controller to be used at the search page with pagination
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setController { get; set, }
    // The list will be shown at the search page
    public List<Accounts> acc { get; set; }

    public PageReference search(){
        String myQuery = 'Select Id, Name From Account Where Amount > 10';
        setController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(myQuery));
        // Here defining pagination step size
        setController.setPageSize(10);
        // Fill out the list to be used at the search page
        acc = (List<Account>) setController.getRecords();
            return null;
    }

    public List<Account> getResults(){
        // Important! Setting the page size back to be able to output ALL records for the pdf
        setController.setPageSize(setController.getResultSize());
        return (List<Account>) setController.getRecords();
    }

    public List<Account> getResultsForPdf(){
        // Important! Setting the page size back to be able to output ALL records for the pdf
        setController.setPageSize(setController.getResultSize());
        return (List<Account>) setController.getRecords();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note also the Wizard CustomController example in the VF official developer's doc - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm  uses multiple pages sharing the same controller with next/previous buttons doing the navigation

Comment: The wizard article has moved to:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm?search_text=wizard